# How to output a range of numbers from a column within a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a  loop that will pull a number or range within a dataframe and stop analyzing the string after the word has been found.

For example:

```
   df['size']=['sz 10-13 of jordan 12', 'size 10 adidas', 
               'size 11 nike air forece 1', 'sz 6-7 jordan 6sz', ‘brand new Sz 11 jordan 5’]
```

I need a function similar to this:

```
def assignSize(row):

    sizeList =[]
    for word in sizeList:
        if word == 'sz' or word == 'size':
            #i do not know what to place here
```

But I would like my output to be:

```
df['size'] =['10-13','10','11','6-7']
```

Basically I want the script to stop reading the string after finding the first number or first range of numbers. So of there is another 'sz' that follows after the initial size or sz, it should not read it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this?:

```
df['size'] = df['size'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[1])
print(df['size'])
```

Output:

```
0    10-13
1       10
2       11
3      6-7
Name: size, dtype: object
```

***Edit***:

Try this:

```
import re
df['size']=['sz 10-13 of jordan 12', 'size 10 adidas', 
               'brand new Sz 13 jordan 5', 'sz 6-7 jordan 6sz']
df['size'] = df['size'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(re.findall(r'\d+', ' '.join(x.split()[:-1]))))
print(df['size'])
```

Output:

```
0    10-13
1       10
2       13
3      6-7
Name: size, dtype: object
```